# C++ refreshing thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have this project I'm working on where I have a label that displays the robot coordinates. However to do (and because of a specific case) I need to make a function run like every 1 second to give me those values.
It would be something like this every second:

```
label1->Text = read_position(axis1);
```

But I have no idea how to make it.. Can please someone help? Thanks !
EDIT: Using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: You probably don't want to have another thread give the GUI thread a value. Bad things will happen when the GUI is part-way through a redraw and the label is changed. Probably be safer for the GUI thread to get the value as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using some GUI framework, i'd advised you not to use multithreading for such a simple thing. For instance, in win32 you can use `SetTimer` function.

Comment: Any suggestion of where to know more about that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In MFC and ATL/WTL there will be more convinient wrapper methods in window classes. Also, you should implement OnTimer handler in the window which is going to receive periodical messages from timer.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the 'multithreading' tag, so I suppose you are free to use multiple threads.  So, the way to do this is by launching a new thread which will be doing the following:

```
while( ! instructed_to_quit() )
{
    give_him_those_values();
    sleep_for_a_second();
}
```

The specifics of precisely how to achieve each of these steps is largely dependent on what kind of system you are running on, which you have been rather secretive about, so if you tell us more about that, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Well the loop is until the gui is closed so I don't think that's to bother (?)
Can you give me like pseudo-code? I have really zero experiencie with threading..

Comment: Sorry! I'm using visual studio 2015, c++ language :)

Comment: Depending on what kind of system you are running on, it may be that every single one of your threads will have to terminate before your application is allowed to terminate.  So, you might *have to* explicitly tell each of your threads to exit, if you do not want your application to appear hung upon termination.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8. Since all tabs of the gui depend on the position and I always need that info, I'd only want the "refreshing" to stop when the .exe is closed

Comment: What I gave you above is pseudo-code.  If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 then most likely your system is Windows.  If you are writing a plain Win32 executable, then the function is `::Sleep( int milliseconds )` and it is usually found in `windows.h`.  (But there is a chance that you might need to look at `Synchapi.h`.)  If you are coding for .Net, then the function would be `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( int milliseconds )`.

Comment: Okay, will give it a try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, do *not* give that a try.  You are now telling us that you are using a GUI, so the right way to do this would be by using a GUI timer.  That would save you from having to spawn and maintain a separate thread.  Also, your would probably run into trouble if you tried to invoke your GUI thread from another thread.  The `SetTimer()` function suggested by @user1736596 is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Visual Studio 2015, you can use standard threads and atomic variables of C++11. There are some different possible solutions, the following is one of them.

```
static MyRobotForm myRobot(void);
static std::thread reader;
static std::atomic<double*> coordinates(nullptr);
static std::atomic<bool> shutdown(false);

static void position_reader() {
   // loop until app is alive
   while(!shutdown) {
       // fetch the coordinates array
       double *temp = read_all_axis(myRobot.Cp, decision);
       // atomically replace the old unused value or nullptr
       temp = coordinates.exchange(temp);
       // it is safe to delete nullptr
       delete temp;
       // sleep for the proper time
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
   }
   // finicky but correct
   delete coordinates.load();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // start the reading thread
    reader = std::thread(position_reader);
    // where depends on gui toolkit ???
    // atomically seize the current value
    double *temp = coordinates.exchange(nullptr);
    if(temp != nullptr) {
        label1->Text = std::string(/*decide how to display temp*/);
        delete temp;
    }
    // on application exit
    shutdown = true;
    reader.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I have not tested it but it should work. What GUI toolkit are you using? *)

Comment: Hi. First of all I don't think I can answar the question about the GUI toolkit, I'm newbie and I have no idea (this might help ? http://prntscr.com/958m0s).
Since this is for the GUI, I don't have a main, where should I put the code?

Comment: And actually there are 5 more coordinates that I need have acess to, not just one

Comment: Nevermind my 1st question, turns out I can't have a main in the gui ^^
I have a function read_all_axis that returns an array with all the positions, if that helps !

Comment: An array of what exactely? Anyway, how did you build the GUI?

Comment: returns an array of doubles (double *read_all_axis(TCommPort *Cp, int decision)). Since VS2015 doesn't allow to create c++ gui (I think) a friend created in VS2013, so I dunno.
Since TCommPort is not static I had to made position_reader only void, is there a problem in that? and also this happens: http://prntscr.com/959ki7
Thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: The static keyword here means something different than inside a class, it is a C keyword that tells the compiler the function belongs only to the current module (main.cpp?). You could incur in problems if somewhere else you declare a function with the same name, so it is safer to leave it. TCommPort is always the same object? Where do you actually store it? As for the thread assignment, you should omit parenthesis, since you are passing a pointer to the function that the thread will call, and not calling the function yourself :)

Comment: Do you have only one MyRobotForm instance for the entire application? It is a bit difficult for me to help you without knowing the general picture.

Comment: Yes, only one instance!

Comment: Look at the code, I have changed it. Now the question is how and where update the GUI.. do you have a class representing the application window or something similar?

Comment: The only thing I have close to that (?) is the MyRobotForm_Load which I don't think is the thing I want so my answer is no... I still get this error btw: http://prntscr.com/95e8qc, http://prntscr.com/95e9ja, http://prntscr.com/95e9oq aaand http://prntscr.com/95ea0k

Comment: Look at the code of the original answer, I have changed a couple of things. For the GUI there should be somewhere the code that implements builds the window, manage events ecc